# How to set up a DNS for multiple websites in different servers at home

Tags: dns, webserver, esxi

I have never done this before and I am not sure if this is doable. My goal is to host several websites in my home in one ESXi server.

I plan to use ESXi server to generate several virtual machines for different website.  I have only one 80 port as I have only one public IP. I hope I can use this port for multiple websites. I don't know how to set up a "DNS system" to direct different traffic request to different website server. I know in Windows we can set up a IIS and then point to different websites. I wanted to be done in Linux equivalent. But the websites are hosting in different machines instead of one web server. Will that be a problem?

Actually it doesn't have to be involved with ESXi server, it can be simpler. The question can be like this: you have several desktops at home and each desktop host one website, you want them to be accessed from outside visitors. I know how to put one website in public. But I don't know how to do multiple website. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It's possible to have multiple physical servers behind one home router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1148679/its-possible-to-have-multiple-physical-servers-behind-one-home-router)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using DNS. DNS (when it comes to the web at least) just maps domain names to IP addresses, which wall all need to be the same static IP.

This leaves you with 2 options for multiple  publicly available websites -

1.use different ports to identify which site - eg http://site.one http://site.two:81 http://site.three:83 and then using port forwarding to redirect to the appropriate internal machine.

2. Use a reverse proxy - send all external requests to 1 machine and let it get the requests as required - including connecting to other machines as appropriate.